# Resetting a bunch of radio buttons

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, dialog, radio-button

I have a dialog box with over 500 radio buttons. I want to create a button for users to click to reset all the radio buttons in case he/she made too many mistakes.

I have tried doing them individually.

```
void DefectConfigurator::OnBnClickedButton2()
{      
        CButton* pBtn1 = (CButton*) GetDlgItem(IDC_AAAA);
        pBtn1->SetCheck(0);
        CButton* pBtn2 = (CButton*) GetDlgItem(IDC_BBBB);
        pBtn2->SetCheck(0);
        CButton* pBtn3 = (CButton*) GetDlgtem(IDC_CCCC);
        pBtn3->SetCheck(0);
            .
            .
            .
```

This way works, but I was wondering if there is a simpler way? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IDC_` control id's are just numbers in the resource.h file. So ensure `IDC_AAAA`, `IDC_BBBB` ... `IDC_ZZZZ`, etc. are sequential with no interruptions. Then just iterate in a `for` loop:

```
for (UINT nID = IDC_AAAA; nID <= IDC_ZZZZ; ++nID)
{
   CButton* pBtn = static_cast<CButton *>(GetDlgItem(nID));
   pBtn->SetCheck(BST_UNCHECKED);
}
```

If you want to be cautious then you could replace `static_cast` with `dynamic_cast` to have runtime type checking and then check for null pointer.

Comment: Oh my. Thank you so much! <3

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way in MFC for exchanging data between the controls and variables is [DDX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-exchange?view=vs-2019). This uses `DoDataExchange` function which is created by MFC Wizard by default (in most cases). The data is exchanged between the UI and the variables both ways by a call to [UpdateData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/standard-dialog-data-exchange-routines?view=vs-2019#ddx_radio) function.

The general idea is to have a variable in your dialog class that holds the current state of the radio group (nothing checked or index of the button that is checked). This is done by [DDX_Radio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/standard-dialog-data-exchange-routines?view=vs-2019#ddx_radio) function. You have a simple example in this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104532/Radio-Buttons-in-MFC-Visual-Studio-2008-C).

Back to your question:

If you have 500 radio buttons, they are probably splited into different groups. The first radio in the group has `WS_GROUP` style and all following radio buttons in the same group must NOT have `WS_GROUP` style.
More info about MFC radio button and DDX [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/standard-dialog-data-exchange-routines?view=vs-2019#ddx_radio).

**Implementation:**

1. Declare a [CMap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmap-class?view=vs-2019) in your dialog header that will hold the state of the radio buttons. It maps between the dialog control ID and the state.

   ```
   CMap <UINT, UINT, int, int> m_Radios;
   ```
2. Here is the DDX function:

   ```
   void CMFC1Dlg::DDX_CustomRadios(CDataExchange* pDX)
   {
       // 1. enumerate all radio groups.
       // 2. call to a DDX_Radio implementation  
       CWnd * wnd = pDX->m_pDlgWnd->GetWindow(GW_CHILD);
       while (wnd)
       {
           // verify if this is radio button with WS_GROUP style.
           if (wnd->GetStyle() & WS_GROUP &&
               wnd->SendMessage(WM_GETDLGCODE, 0, 0L) & DLGC_RADIOBUTTON)
           {           
   #define CLEAR_STATE -1
               int radioState = CLEAR_STATE;
               int radioId = wnd->GetDlgCtrlID();

               if(!pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate)
                   if (!m_Radios.Lookup(radioId, radioState))
                       m_Radios[radioId] = radioState;

               DDX_Radio(pDX, radioId, radioState);

               m_Radios[radioId] = radioState;
           }

           wnd = wnd->GetNextWindow();
       }
   ```
3. Add a call to DoDataExchange:

   ```
   void CMFC1Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
   {
       CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX); 

       DDX_CustomRadios(pDX);
   }
   ```

**Usage:**

Clear all radio buttons:

```
    void CMFC1Dlg::OnBnClearAll()
    {
        m_Radios.RemoveAll();

        UpdateData(FALSE); // this updates the ui
    }
```

Save all buttons state from UI to the variables:

```
    void CMFC1Dlg::OnBnSaveAll()
    {
        UpdateData(TRUE);

        POSITION pos = m_Radios.GetStartPosition();
        while (pos != NULL)
        {
            UINT nId = 0;
            BOOL state = 0;

            m_Radios.GetNextAssoc(pos, nId, state);

            TRACE("Control: %d State: %d\r\n", nId, state);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use the `CheckRadioButton()` Win32 function:

```
CheckRadioButton(m_hWnd, IDC_AAAA, IDC_AAAA + 500 - 1, -1);
```

Haven't tested it but pls check these two points:

- The documentation dosn't specifically mention it, but the `nIDLastButton` argument seem to be inclusive, so I used `IDC_AAAA + 500 - 1`.
- I set `nIDCheckButton` to -1, this should cause no radio button to be checked.

You could instead elect to use DDX/DDV, the `DDX_Radio()` function does all the work for you (write AND read data). Set the variable to -1 before calling `UpdateData(FALSE)`. Remember, this is an index into the radio-group, not a control identifier.

As a sidenote, isn't a UI with 500 radio-buttons really VERY cluttered? Consider using a drop-down list instead. Or you mean check-boxes instead of radio buttons? A "Defect-Configuration" using radio-buttons would allow only one "defect" to be selected.